# problem with connecting the server and downloading the data

Tags: objective-c, web-services, ios

i am trying to download the data from the server for that i wrote code with in the action method but it is not at all help full.can any one tell me the exact way to connect and download the data from the server.

```
-(IBAction)download {    
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"books"]; 

NSURL *downloadUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"url contains   .zip file"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:downloadUrl];
NSLog(@"%@",data);

[data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
NSLog(@"final line");

NSLog(@"%@",data);

NSData *newdata=[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];

NSLog(@"the new data %@",newdata);*/

}
```

Comment: What happens when this code runs? What error are you getting? "but it is not at all help full" also doesn't help us know what the problem is.

Comment: the url(server) contains .zip file  i am trying to download and save it into my documents directory .

Comment: That didn't answer the question. -_-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:60];
    connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];                                                                                                                                                                                               - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)theConnection didReceiveData:(NSData *)incrementalData   // Call when data is received from url
{  
    if (data==nil) data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    [data appendData:incrementalData];
}
```

Comment: you can use this way. I use the connection methods to download image from url. You can use it to download the zip file